# Code failing to execute Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know it's a bit odd but I've written this code that launches a specific view controller when the user clicks on a push notification. The code works perfectly when I run it on my device, but the second I unplug my device from Xcode and run it again the code doesn't execute and the view controller doesn't open when I click on a push notification.

Here is the code I have for opening my view controller in my Appdelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

if(apsInfo) {
    //there is some pending push notification, so do something
    //in your case, show the desired viewController in this if block
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
    NotificationViewController *pvc = [vc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Alerts"];

    [vc presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}


}
```

if more info is needed please say so.

Thanks in advance, 
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard;
      storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
      self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Alerts"];
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Try this one.. It should work.

Comment: okay so it turns out that it works if the app is still alive in the background but when i remove the app from the background then the view controller doesn't launch anymore...

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryBoardName" bundle:nil];
    NotificationViewController *pvc = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Alerts"];
[self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I seem to be getting error "Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type AppDelegate

Comment: Thanks for the comment I'll try out the code now, although I suggest you change self to [pvc presentViewController: pic animated: YES completion:nil];